# Java include class in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I don't understand why i cannot include a class into my jsp file.
So, the file i want to use is:
public_html/admin/dashboard.jsp
i have this code:

```
<%@page import="frontEnd.General"%>
<%
String getBasePath = General.getBasePath(request);  
%>
```

the class i want to include is located:
public_html/WEB-INF/classes/frontEnd/General.class

but when i do this i recieve the error:
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP

Can you help me with this?
Thanks!

---

another relevant example:
i have a page, page.jsp in route that has this code on the top:

```
<%@page import="frontEnd.General"%>
<%
String getBasePath = General.getBasePath(request);  
%>
```

if i access like this:
www.mydomain.com/page.jsp - works, the class is found

if i move the file into a directory (let's say "admin") and try to access the file like:
www.mydomain.com/admin/page.jsp - i recieve the error that the class is not found

Comment: Is class `General` in the package `frontEnd` (in other words, do you have `package frontEnd;` at the top of `General.java`?) Do you have a more detailed error message that provides more information about why the JSP could not be compiled?

Comment: i forgot to tell you that i recieve this error after i upload the project on a server. On localhost works ok! And yes, on the top of General class i have package frontEnd;

Comment: and what is strange, it i use this code on a file that is in public_html there it works, but if i move the file inside a folder, then appear the problem

Comment: `package frontEnd; public class General {}`?  (Please no capitals in package names.)

Answer (score 0):

Check the package structure of your server. Most probably it doesnt find the class in your structure hence it throw compilation error.
Try importing other classes and check whether problem still comes.

Comment: i tried but same error. but i think is like i said upper: "and what is strange, it i use this code on a file that is in public_html there it works, but if i move the file inside a folder, then appear the problem" but don't know how to resolve this

Comment: Check whether you have execute rights over that folder